# JavaScript Dynamic Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, calendar

I am programming a dynamic javascript calendar on which events can be added by two persons, the manager and the associate. But, only the text box with the mentioned date appears on the browser. 
Is there a mistake in the logic?
Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.calendarMonth{
border-collapse:collapse;
background-color:#eef;
}
.calendarMonth th{
}
.calendarMonth .calendarTitle{
background-color:#ddf;
}
.calendarMonth .calendarPrevious{
background-color:#ddf;
}
.calendarMonth .calendarNext{
background-color:#ddf;
}
.calendarEmpty{
}
.calendarDay{
background:#fff;
border:1px solid black;
text-align:center;
width:2em;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var  daysInMonth=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
var  monthNames=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

// Returns the number of days in the month in a given year (January=0)
function getDaysInMonth(month,year){
if ((month==1)&&(year%4==0)&&((year%100!=0)||(year%400==0))){
return 29;
}else{
return daysInMonth[month];
}
}

// Performs an action when a date is clicked
function dateClicked(day,month,year){
document.forms.calendar.date.value = day+'/'+month+'/'+year;  

}

// Sets the displayed month
function setDisplayedMonth(month){
if (month<0){
alert('You have reached the beginning of this calendar');
}else if (month>=months){
alert('You have reached the end of this calendar');
}else{
for (var i=0;i<months;i++){
document.getElementById('calendarMonth'+i).style.display='none';
}
document.getElementById('calendarMonth'+month).style.display='block';
}
}
</script>
</head> 

<body>
<form id="calendar">
<table>
<tr>
<td><label for="date">Date:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="28/05/2015"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td><td>
<script type="text/javascript">
var month=0;
var year=2015;
var months=12;
for (var i=0;i<months;i++){
document.writeln('<table class="calendarMonth" '+'id="calendarMonth'+i+'" cellspacing="0">');
 document.writeln('<tr>'
          +'<th class="calendarPrevious" onClick="setDisplayedMonth('+(i-1)+')"><</th>'+'<th class="calendarTitle" colspan="5">'            +monthNames[month]+' '+year+'</th>'+'<th class="calendarNext" onClick="setDisplayedMonth('+(i+1)+')">></th>'+'</tr>');

document.writeln('<tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th>'+'<th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr>');
var firstDayDate=new Date(year,month,1);
var firstDay=firstDayDate.getDay();
for (j=0;j<42;j++){
if (j%7==0) document.write('<tr>')
if ((j=firstDay+getDaysInMonth(month,year))){
document.write('<td class="calendarEmpty"></td>');
}else{
document.write('<td class="calendarDay" '+'onClick="dateClicked('+(j-firstDay+1)+','+(month+1)+','+year+')">'+(j-firstDay+1)+'');
}
if (j%7==6) document.write('</tr>');
}
document.writeln('</table>');
month++;
if (month>=12){
month=0;
year++;
}
}
setDisplayedMonth(5);
</script>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, how can I highlight the date selected by a manager on the associate calendar?

Comment: Are you trying to let the user select a data by clicking on it?  If using jquery.ui is an option, you can use https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ which provides you with a control to select dates.

Comment: Jquery.ui is definitely a good option.. but how do I highlight a date selected by a manager on it? The associate must be able to see his manager selected date and his choice of date highlighted on it when the page loads. Is it possible to do this on the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery ui datepicker and use option `beforeShowDay` to highlight dates

```js
$(function() {
  var specialDates = {};
  var now = new Date();
  specialDates['10' + now.getMonth() + '' + now.getFullYear()] = [true, 'mg-special', 'By Manager'];
  specialDates['25' + now.getMonth() + '' + now.getFullYear()] = [true, 'as-special', 'By Associate'];
  var others = [true, '', ''];
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    'beforeShowDay': function(date) {
      var target = date.getDate() + '' + date.getMonth() + '' + date.getFullYear();
      return specialDates[target] || others;
    },
    'inline': true
  });
});
```

```css
td.mg-special {
  background: sandybrown;
}
td.as-special {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have revised my response having not got it right first time:
try replacing your for loop with:

```
for (j=0; j<42; j++){
if (j%7==0) {document.write('<tr>')};
var l=firstDay;
var k=firstDay+getDaysInMonth(month,year);
if (j>=k){
document.write('<td class="calendarEmpty"></td>');
}else if (j<l){
document.write('<td class="calendarEmpty"></td>');
}else{
document.write('<td class="calendarDay" '+'onClick="dateClicked('+(j-firstDay+1)+','+(month+1)+','+year+',this)">'+(j-firstDay+1)+'');
}
if (j%7==6) document.write('</tr>');
}
```

regarding highlighting the cell on select by manager, you already have a cell click function so build on that e.g by using:

```
// Performs an action when a date is clicked
function dateClicked(day,month,year,obj){
document.forms.calendar.date.value = day+'/'+month+'/'+year;  
obj.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
}
```

note the addition of "this" to the onclick event.

For any more detail i would need to know how your differentiating between inputs made by manager or associate.

if you are intending to bring the managers date in as being set somewhere else as somedate, you could try something like this in place of your for loop:

```
var firstDayDate=new Date(year,month,1);
var firstDay=firstDayDate.getDay();
var managersdate=new Date (somedate);
var managersday=managersdate.getDay();
var managersmonth=managersdate.getMonth();
for (j=0; j<42; j++){
if (j%7==0) {document.write('<tr>')};
var l=firstDay;
var k=firstDay+getDaysInMonth(month,year);
if (j>=k){
document.write('<td class="calendarEmpty"></td>');
}else if (j<l){
document.write('<td class="calendarEmpty"></td>');
}else{
if(j-l==managersday && i==managersmonth){
document.write('<td class="calendarDay" style="background-Color:Yellow" '+'onClick="dateClicked('+(j-firstDay+1)+','+(month+1)+','+year+',this)">'+(j-firstDay+1)+'');
}else{document.write('<td class="calendarDay" '+'onClick="dateClicked('+(j-firstDay+1)+','+(month+1)+','+year+',this)">'+(j-firstDay+1)+'');
}
}
```

It may also be nice to add a hover color of your choosing via css:

```
.calendarDay:hover {background-color: green}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this to be a locally stored CSV (ie on the same domain as your js)? If so then you can grab it via ajax and parse regularly to a var that will become 'somedate' in the above script. I am trying to think how a managers date would sit in a CSV? Would this be a whole series of dates that need iterating through and all placing on the calendar, or perhaps a single date in a known position in the CSV, OE even as a series of value pairs? All of these will determine how you need to parse your CSV.

Comment: I would also ask are you sure this has to be pure JS and youre absoloutly unable to use the jquery posted by @Arvind ? Jquery is perfect for handling datepickers, Ajax calls and parsing CSV, it can simplify all this down to a much shorter code.

Answer (score 0):

I think its worthwhile responding to your comment about retrieving and parsing csv as a seperate question.
Parsing is in common language the splitting of a sentence into its component words. Most commonly we would use it to 'parse or split' data held in formats such as XML or JSON which i recomend you look at as more capable methods, but CSV is still a valid format.

Firstly retrieving your csv, if we were using jquery it would be:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ManagersDates.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
     });
```

there are even shorter methods available via get and post in jquery.

But presuming you wish to stick with JS for this too (no jquery) then the following is about as simple as we can get to retrieve your csv:

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // you may use "new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")" for ie6 and below
    request.open('GET', 'ManagersDates.csv', false);
    request.send();
    var managersdate=(request.responsetext);
```

your csv now exists in the variable "managersdate" but you need to "Split or Parse" it from one long string into its component parts, there are plenty of ways to do this one method is as follows:

```
var mdates = new Array();
mdates = managersdate.split(",");
```

you now have an array holding your csv values and need to extract the correct date from it, if your date is the third item (count starts at 0) then this should return your date:

```
managersdate=(mdates[2]);
```

There are tons of excelent posts on parsing data and plenty on JSON and XML that are well worth looking up.
Good luck

Comment: as an adendum to the above I would also recomend you look at other JS date functions including Date.parseExact.